# How to change node ID on graphlib?

Tags: javascript, graph

I have a graph defined with [cpettitt/graphlib](https://github.com/cpettitt/graphlib).

Is there any easy way to change the ID of a node also updating any edges ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, create a copy of the node with a new ID and its edges. Then remove the old node.

```
changeId(current, newId) {
    let g = this.getGraph();

    // Change on graph
    let node = g.node(current);
    let inEdges = g.inEdges(current);
    let outEdges = g.outEdges(current);

    // Create new node
    node.id = newId;
    g.setNode(newId, node);
    // Create new edges
    for (let i = 0; i < inEdges.length; i++) {
        let edge = inEdges[i];
        let conn = g.edge(edge.v, current);
        conn.target = newId;
        g.setEdge(edge.v, newId, conn);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < outEdges.length; i++) {
        let edge = outEdges[i];
        let conn = g.edge(current, edge.w);
        conn.source = newId;
        g.setEdge(newId, edge.w, conn);
    }
    // Remove old node
    g.removeNode(current);
}
```